# Log json serialization errors in Application Insights

Tags: json.net, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I run a Azure Function with [openapi extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension).

To get the correct nullable values into the openapi definition I use the `DisallowNull` property of the DTO.

```cs
    public record MyObject(
        [property: JsonProperty(Required = Required.DisallowNull)]
        string ContinuationToken);
```

I had a bug, that one property had a DisallowNull, but there ware cases where null was possible.

After understanding the error I reproduces i local a got a helpful message:

```
[2021-12-15T12:41:06.365Z] Newtonsoft.Json: Cannot write a null value for property 'continuationToken'. Property requires a non-null value. Path ''.
```

With this the errors was quickly fixed, but when I look into the Application Insights logs, I see nothing of the error. Only a Response code 500 in the request indicates the error.

[image: Application Insights logs]

Is it possible to get serialization errors of Azure Functions in Application insights log?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions  provides **built-in integration** with Azure Application Insights to **monitor functions**. **Application Insights can collects log, performance, and error data**. By detecting performance anomalies and using analytics tools, we can easily diagnose issues and better understand the issue.

With Application Insights integration enabled, telemetry data is sent to your connected Application Insights instance. This data includes logs generated by the Functions host, traces written from your functions code, and performance data. Following are some example of types of log with description.

| Log Level | Code | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Warning | 3 | Logs that highlight an abnormal or unexpected event in the application flow, but don't stop execution. |
| Error | 4 | Logs that highlight when the current flow of execution is stopped because of a failure. |
| Critical | 5 | Logs that describe an unrecoverable application or system crash, or a catastrophic failure that requires immediate attention. |

**The [*host.json*  file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json) configuration determines how much logging a functions app sends to Application Insights**. For more information read this [host.json reference for Azure Functions 2.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json) Microsoft document.

I would suggest to read this [Monitor Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#collecting-telemetry-data) document for more information. Also check this [How to configure monitoring for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2) using Application Insights.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have set up Application insight and most of the messages and errors showing up. But Newtonsoft.Json serialization errors are not to find there. So I need more details how I get it.